# MySQL Search for values in the cell and count them

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I built a poll system. In this system, the values selected by the user are saved as 0,1,2. Now I want each user's choices to be counted.

For example:

- Option one: 10 votes
- Option two: 5 votes
- Option three: 12 votes
- ...

[image: Screenshot of table in database]

```
foreach ($choices as $choice) {
       echo $wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mytable WHERE (id = {$_GET['id']} AND user_choice = {$choice}))");          
}
```

Comment: you are going to face very hard times for a poor database design. Never store multiple values togheter in the same cell. Use multiple rows each with just one vote each and it will be really easy to query it

Answer (score 0):

try this:

user_choice: Column containing user votes

```
$sql=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT user_choice  FROM mytable WHERE (id = {$_GET['id']} AND user_choice = {$choice}) ");
$arr = array();
while ($all = mysqli_fetch_array($sql, MYSQLI_NUM)) {
foreach($all as $val) {
$arr[] = $val;
}    
}
$vote_choice = array_count_values($arr);
foreach($vote_choice as $name=>$qty) {
echo "Who Choice(".$name.'):->'.$qty.'<br />';
}
```